# Multi-touch drawing : action_cancel when the palm touches the screen

Tags: android, touch, drawing, multi-touch, palm

I'm working on an android application on tablet to draw every points touched by the finger or the hand. It is very important for the application to track not only the fingers but also the palm (even if it's not drawing the exact touched area but only a thin path, as long as we can see the movement of the palm it's fine). A good example of what I want to do is the "show pointer location" in the Android developer menu : if the drawing could be exactly like this, that would be perfect.

I managed to code a multi-touch drawing app, but the problem I have here is that every time the touched area is too wide (for example when I touch the screen with my entire palm), the application stops drawing (even the fingers drawings stops) and I have this error in the log : **[ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:1.4225352** (the number after "eccen" changes depending on the size of my palm touch).

I'm quite new to android, I spent a lot of time searching how I could prevent this action_cancel but I couldn't find anything that makes it work... I tried to prevent the parent views from taking control of the onTouch events, but it didn't work. So if you have any idea of how I can manage that, it would be great :)

Thanks !

(English is not my native language, so don't hesitate to ask me to reformulate is something is not clear)